# How do you control which photo Facebook uses for their Save Button

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

The button works fine, but it seems to grab a random image from my page which has up to 20 photos. I added the following meta tag but it is not taking that image. Any suggestions?

```
meta property="og:image" content="http://www.oahure.com/data/2016/201606179/2.jpg" />
```

Comment: Did you debug the URL? https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object/

Comment: Yes, the URL does point to the image I want to use and when I put it in the debugger the correct image shows.